# Splitting Flask app into several files; Trouble with module importing

Tags: python, import, flask, sqlalchemy, models

I'm trying to split a Flask app into several files and I've hit a snag with all the module imports.

Hopefully someone can shed some light o this issue...

This is the error I get:

```
NameError: global name 'db' is not defined
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fqKr.png

I have this file/folder structure:

```
├── Pluto
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── pluto_admin.py
│   ├── pluto.db
│   ├── pluto_db.py
│   ├── pluto_home.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── img
│   │   └── js
│   └── templates
└── run.py
```

**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask

pluto = Flask(__name__)

""" imports """
import Pluto.pluto_db
import Pluto.pluto_home
import Pluto.pluto_admin
```

pluto_db.py:

```
from Pluto import pluto
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

pluto.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:////var/www/flask/pluto_dev/Pluto/pluto.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(pluto)

""" MODELS """

class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(254), unique=True, nullable=False)
    nume = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    prenume = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User %r>" % (self.email)
```

pluto_home.py:

```
from Pluto import pluto

@pluto.route("/")
def index():
    users = db.Users.query.all()
    return users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to add this to pluto_home.py

```
from pluto_db import db
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'Users'

Comment: Apparently if I do

    from pluto_db import *

it works with Users.query.all()

however, is there any way I can import this module globally, without having to do it in every file?

Comment: No, you can't. A better option is from pluto_db import Users